# firebase indexin method ? error in android

Tags: android, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with firebase when I need to Apply the Query .

give me error message like this

> Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "username"' at Books to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

this is my code :

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("****/books");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(true);
    final FirebaseListAdapter<Books> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Books>(this,Books.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Books model, int position) {
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

            Typeface Myfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/gernralfont.ttf");

            textView1.setTypeface(Myfont);
            textView2.setTypeface(Myfont);
            textView2.setTextSize(17);
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6eaafc"));
            textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4d70a0"));
            textView1.setText( "\n" + model.getUsername() +"\n" );
            textView2.setText("-"+model.getBookhave()+ "\n");
        }
    };


    hilist.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

i read some posts in internet talk about 'Indexin' with firebase rules ? 
i dont understand what mean ? please help me to save my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [rules tab of the Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules) of your project.

You will find something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Under the rules node, add a child for your index. So if you start with the above, it becomes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "Books": {
      ".indexOn": "username"
    }
  }
}
```

Then publish your rules. With this instruction, the Firebase Database server will create an index for the username of each book. This allows it to perform queries on the user name on the server.